# How to index percolator queries containing filters on inner objects?

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Elasticsearch 2.1.1

I have documents with inner objects:

```
{
    "level1": {
        "level2": 42
    }
}
```

I want to register percolator queries applying filters on the inner property:

```
$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/myindex/.percolator/myquery?pretty -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "level1.level2": {
                        "gt": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

It fails because I don't have a mapping:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "query_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "Strict field resolution and no field mapping can be found for the field with name [level1.level2]",
      "index" : "myindex",
      "line" : 1,
      "col" : 58
    } ],
    "type" : "percolator_exception",
    "reason" : "failed to parse query [myquery]",
    "index" : "myindex",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "query_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "Strict field resolution and no field mapping can be found for the field with name [level1.level2]",
      "index" : "myindex",
      "line" : 1,
      "col" : 58
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

So I start again, but this time I add a mapping template before:

```
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/_template/myindex
curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/myindex
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_template/myindex?pretty -d 'x
{             
  "template": "myindex",
  "mappings" : {
    "mytype" : {
      "properties" : {
        "level1" : {
          "properties" : {
            "level2" : {
              "type" : "long"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

I try to register my percolator query again:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/myindex/.percolator/myquery?pretty -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "level1.level2": {
                        "gt": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

And now it succeeds:

```
{
  "_index" : "myindex",
  "_type" : ".percolator",
  "_id" : "myquery",
  "_version" : 1,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "created" : true
}
```

And I can see the mapping that has been created:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/myindex/_mapping?pretty
{
  "myindex" : {
    "mappings" : {
      ".percolator" : {
        "properties" : {
          "query" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "enabled" : false
          }
        }
      },
      "mytype" : {
        "properties" : {
          "level1" : {
            "properties" : {
              "level2" : {
                "type" : "long"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now my problem is that I also need to perform searches *on my percolator queries* and [the default percolate mapping doesn’t index the query field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-percolate.html#_indexing_percolator_queries).

So I start again, this time specifying in my mapping template that I want percolator queries to be indexed (note `"enabled": true`):

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_template/myindex?pretty -d ' 
{
  "template": "myindex",
  "mappings" : {
    ".percolator" : {
      "properties" : {
        "query" : {
          "type" : "object",
          "enabled" : true
        }
      }
    },
    "mytype" : {
      "properties" : {
        "level1" : {
          "properties" : {
            "level2" : {
              "type" : "long"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

I try to register my percolator query again:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/myindex/.percolator/myquery?pretty -d '{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "range": {
                    "level1.level2": {
                        "gt": 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

But now I get an error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [ {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "Field name [level1.level2] cannot contain '.'"
    } ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Field name [level1.level2] cannot contain '.'"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

How can I create *and* index a percolator query matching an inner property?